# How to get specific records in a list of a list

Tags: c#, json

I'm having an issue trying to loop through a list with lists that relate to each other and gather them to write to a json node. I have classes like this:

```
public class RequiredField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; } //varchar(100)
    public List<RequiredFieldColumnValue> RequiredFieldColumnValues { get; set; }
}
public class RequiredFieldColumnValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
```

An example response would look like:

```
var requiredFields = new List<RequiredField>
{
    new RequiredField
    {
        FieldName = "FirstName",
        RequiredFieldColumnValues = new List<RequiredFieldColumnValue>
        {
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 0, ItemNumber = 1, LineNumber = 1, Value = "Dave"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 1, ItemNumber = 1, LineNumber = 1, Value = "Joey"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 2, ItemNumber = 1, LineNumber = 1, Value = "Derek"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 3, ItemNumber = 3, LineNumber = 2, Value = "Bill"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 4, ItemNumber = 3, LineNumber = 3, Value = "Steve"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 5, ItemNumber = 3, LineNumber = 3, Value = "James"},
        }
    },
    new RequiredField
    {
        FieldName = "LastName",
        RequiredFieldColumnValues = new List<RequiredFieldColumnValue>
        {
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 0, ItemNumber = 1, LineNumber = 1, Value = "Smith"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 1, ItemNumber = 1, LineNumber = 1, Value = "Pell"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 2, ItemNumber = 1, LineNumber = 1, Value = "Duncan"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 3, ItemNumber = 3, LineNumber = 2, Value = "Gutmann"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 4, ItemNumber = 3, LineNumber = 3, Value = "Rogers"},
            new RequiredFieldColumnValue 
                {Id = 5, ItemNumber = 3, LineNumber = 3, Value = "Johnson"},
        }
    },
};
```

Now the problem is how to I write these to a JArray(); that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Item": 1,
    "Lines": [
      {
        "LineNumber": 1,
        "buyer": [
          {
            "FirstName": "Dave",
            "LastName": "Smith"
          },
          {
            "FirstName": "Joey",
            "LastName": "Pell"
          },
          {
            "FirstName": "Derek",
            "LastName": "Duncan"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Item": 3,
    "Lines": [
      {
        "LineNumber": 2,
        "buyer": [
          {
            "FirstName": "Bill",
            "LastName": "Gutmann"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "LineNumber": 3,
    "buyer": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Steve",
        "LastName": "Rogers"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "James",
        "LastName": "Johnson"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried looping through the FieldNames but then I had all results for one field name and had to find the same id within the other FieldNames but I was still in the loop. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this turned out to be quite simple.

```
var fieldList = requiredField.SelectMany(
    a => a.RequiredFieldColumnValues
        .Select(b => new
        {
            a.FieldName ,
            b.Id,
            b.Value
        })).GroupBy(x=>x.Id)
        .Select(to=> new
    {
        Id = to.Key,
        Group = to
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

this flattened the entire list then i was able to group it by the ID. Then loop through it to create the json:

```
buyer = new JArray();

if (fieldList.Any())
{
    foreach (var properties in fieldList)
    {
        dynamic savableObject = new JObject();
        foreach (var property in properties.Group)
        {
            savableObject.Add(property.FieldName, property.Value);
        }
     buyer.Add(savableObject);
    }
}
```

Buyer then output:

```
{[
  {
    "FirstName": "Dave",
    "LastName": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Joey",
    "LastName": "Pell"
  },...
```

then i can just wrap the array with the ItemNumber and LineArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use JSON.Net library which is available in Nuget package manager, this will allow you to use json serialization/deserialization.

Serializing your object to json will convert your object into a json string (which is looking like what you want).

**Serialization :** (using the requiredFields object you have in your code, assuming that it is already created)

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requiredFields);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString); // Just to see the output
```

**Deserialization :** (using the jsonString output from above)

```
var myNewObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RequiredField>>(jsonString);
```

For deserialization, you have to specify the destination type between <> in `DeserializeObject<>`

Don't forget to import Json.Net at the top of your file with `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Hope this help !